# What is <String> for in Java?

Tags: java, generics, casting

`Listernterface<String> runnerList = new AList<String>();`

I thought casting uses parenthesis. Can someone please explain to me the difference?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Java generic, which is a way of having classes, methods, etc. which work for multiple types. For example, you can have a `ListInterface<String>`, `ListInterface<Integer>`, etc. Whatever's contained in the angle brackets is a type parameter, which is a special parameter that tells Java what type we're using.

Try this [tutorial from Sun for more.](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

[Casting](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-object-typecasting) has little to do with [generics](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf), which is what the angle bracket syntax is used for here. Casting always uses regular brackets, ( and ), and is used to tell the compiler that you can guarantee an object that it's got is an object of a more specific type. Generics are usually read of a CLASS of GENERICTYPE, for instance a `List<String>` is a list of strings.

Comment: My primary use of java generics is essentially auto-casting, and so I think that saying they've got nothing to do with each other is a bit strong.

Comment: True - I meant functionally they're entirely different rather than being in any way related just because they use different types of brackets!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a cast, it is the invocation of a *generic class*.  Here is a good place to start: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Read about Java generics.

In this case, we have a data structure that could hold any kind of Object. But, we want to specify what kind of Object that this particular instance is storing.

So here, we're saying that

a `ListInterface` of `String`s called `runnerList` is now a `new` instance of an `AList` of `String`s.

Answer (score 0):

This is Java Generics in action [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/generics.html) or [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjava.sun.com%2Fj2se%2F1.5%2Fpdf%2Fgenerics-tutorial.pdf&rct=j&q=java%20generics&ei=PQpGTfWbLoS8lQeoqsg6&usg=AFQjCNHlDA-kbX-h4ixgUmBJK6VZNRVENw&sig2=mMLaykVzDLzGxReySCj9aA&cad=rja), might help. But basically the above indicates that AList is some kind of List that accepts only Strings, and that runnerList is a list interface that will only return Strings or accept Strings for the relevant methods.